# How to replace what is inside a text box with a new input -java script

Tags: javascript

I am creating an online calculator but I am having trouble when a user enters their equation in the text box I can get the equation evaluated and displayed in the console log but, I can't get it to replace the equation with the answer. If “=” is clicked, it should evaluate the equation in the textbox and replace the equation with the answer. This is what I have so far.

```
 const equalsButton = document.querySelector('input[value="="]').onclick = function(){
    var inputVar = document.querySelector('[name=equation]').value
   
    console.log(eval(inputVar));
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't provide your `html` code, and since you use `eval` - take a look on this demo for simple calculator:

```js
let total = []; // this will hold the arguments 
const equalsButton = document.querySelectorAll('input'); // calculator buttons 
for (var i = 0; i < equalsButton.length; i++) { // iterate the buttons
    equalsButton[i].addEventListener('click', function() { // listen to click 
        document.querySelector('#result').textContent += this.value; // add the clicked value to the screen
        if (this.value === '=') { // if equal clicked - show result
            document.querySelector('#result').textContent = eval(total.join('')); // result would be calculated from the total array arguments
        }        
        else { // any other clicked buttons
            total.push(this.value); // would be add to the array that would be the result when '=' would be clicked
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<div id="result" style="font-size: larger;"></div>
<div>
    <input type="button" value="0">
    <input type="button" value="1">
    <input type="button" value="2">
    <input type="button" value="3">
    <input type="button" value="4">
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="5">
    <input type="button" value="6">
    <input type="button" value="7">
    <input type="button" value="8">
    <input type="button" value="9">
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="+">
    <input type="button" value="-">
    <input type="button" value="/">
    <input type="button" value="*">
    <input type="button" value="=">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the result to get replace the equation, then you could simply reset the input of equation with the equation's solution :

```
    inputVar = eval(inputVar);
```

Comment: Thank you, instead, I did this. document.querySelector('[name=equation]').value = eval(inputVar)

Comment: great i am glad to help
By the way, doing ```document.querySelector('[name=equation]').value = eval(inputVar)``` is better than store it in inputVar and then re-assign it !